# Conversion factor for conductivity of an aqueous solution

Tags: conductivity

I am not 100% sure if this is the right place to ask, but please point me in the right direction if not.

I am designing a conductivity meter, and when it comes to displaying the results in mS/cm or µS/cm, I also need to convert to EC. The first place I found was [THIS](https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/en-US/electric-conductivity/14-9/electrical%20conductivity%20unit-siemens/centimeter/) website which seems great as it has all the units that I can convert here and there, no problem. This site states that 1EC is equal to 1µS/cm.

I had started to do most of my calculations based on the conversions from this website. However, when getting a reference calibration liquid, I noticed it was set to 2.76EC/2.8mS, which goes against what was stated in the website. I then found [THIS](https://www.lenntech.com/calculators/conductivity/tds_engels.htm) website which shows 1EC as equal to 1mS/cm. I have now seen another place online (closed the tab and can't find it!) that also agrees with this.

Another website I have found [HERE](http://www.maherjabado.com/EC-measurments.htm) gives a bit more information on the conversion, and states that EC is measured in deciSiemens per meter (dS/m), and 1EC = 1dS/m, which would be 1mS/cm. Then later, it has a conversion thing at the bottom which has a statement saying:

> Conversions:

> 1 deciSiemens per meter (dS/m) = 1 mmho/cm = 1
> milliSiemens per cm (mS/cm) = 1000 microSiemens per cm (uS/cm) 1
> mhos/cm = 1 S/cm = 1000 mS/cm

> Electrical Conductivity units (EC's) IF
> measured in uS/cm: 1 EC= 1uS/cm = 0.001 dS/m = 0.001 mS/cm = 1 mS/m

> (Example 1.5 dS/m = 1.5 mS/cm = 1500 uS/cm = 1500 EC)

And surely that contradicts itself where it says 1EC = 1µS/cm, then the example after says that is not the case?

I just wanted to ask and be sure on this.... When converting, is 1EC equal to 1mS/cm, or 1µS/cm?

Comment: Your question is not clear, because you have forgotten to mention the unit meter or centimeter in you last sentence.

Comment: @Maurice edited to sort that out. I don't think it really made the question unclear. It is pretty obvious what it meant so the downvote was probably a bit harsh for that. I assume that was yourself. If so, I hope the edit is enough to reverse it

Comment: For the 2 guys downvoting, it would be nice to leave a comment to explain why you feel the downvotes were deserved so I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, it's amazing what can happen if you interpret something literally. In one of the documents you link to it says "EC units". This could be interpreted to mean either "the set of units EC" or "the units for the property EC".   It seems at some point (and IMHO somewhat bizarrely) "EC" has been adopted by some as a convenient shorthand for a particular set of conductivity units (mS/cm or $\mu$ s/cm). Another link does state

> An electrical conductivity unit is a decimal unit of electrical conductivity, which by definition is equal to 1 microsiemens per centimeter (μS/cm). 1 EC = 1 μS/cm. The unit is often used on conductivity meters made in the USA.

However this is highly unorthodox, if not absolutely horrendous abuse of nomenclature, and it is not surprising you are confused. Good job by M Farooq in pointing this out.

My recommendation is to find the manual for the instrument you are using and read it. Some instruments allow display of measurements in different units. Compare those if available to determine the appropriate conversion factors.

In addition, when you do convert from electrical conductivity units to TDS, keep in mind that TDS is not a unit of conductivity. The result depends on different scales that assume different proportionality constants between TDS and conductivity based on different calibrations. Use the conversion that makes sense for your situation.

Comment: I'm fine with the conversion from ED to TDS, that's not a problem. The issue is we want to sell this product to the US market where they do tend to use EC as a unit. The manuals I have seen just tell you how to change the display units, not what they mean. It does seem to be that the majority of places tend to convert 1EC to being 1mS/cm, so I may have to go along with that. Unfortunately, I get told to design to the brief supplied by the sales team....

Comment: No serious researcher should buy a meter with EC written on it without providing *any* units in the manual.

Comment: @M.Farooq well, then it's lucky I'm not a serious researcher in chemistry then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have badly confused yourself by mixing the concept of a property of a solution with the units used to express this property.

Total dissolved solids (TDS) is a property of a solution. Theoretically, it can have any units kg/ kg of a solution, part per million, percentage, or whatever you like. However, people have standardized what they mean by TDS is usually mg solids/L of solution or even ppm.

In the same way, EC is electrical conductivity. It is a property of a solution. It can be expressed in units of microSiemens/cm or any multiple of it. EC itself is not a unit.

Comment: When you look online, there are places that use EC as a unit in some conductivity meters. I believe it happens often in America mainly. I understand what TDS and ED are, but I have seen places using EC as a unit, and it has been a requirement of this project

Comment: Do not trust everything online.

Comment: It is in multiple places online about this subject, plus a lot of conductivity/TDS meters include EC units as one of the units to display measurements in. So there is an answer to this question.

Comment: Have you checked the manuals of those meters? EC unit has to be defined. It does not mean anything on its own. You have to find authentic information from the manual because **EC is not a unit, it is a property**. Did you see this website "EC units: Electrical conductivity can be expressed using a number of different units, but the typical unit is siemens per meter2 per mole (S/m2/mole) or millisiemens per centimetre (mS/cm). The mS/cm unit is generally used in Europe as a guide to the concentration of nutrients in water. "?

Comment: https://www.canna-uk.com/electrical-conductivity#:~:text=EC%20units,concentration%20of%20nutrients%20in%20water.

Comment: I haven't looked at the manuals of all of them. The one I have looked at just mentions how to switch between displaying mS/cm, EC and ppm. The more I have looked, the more it is looking like 1EC is equal to 1mS/cm in most places